# Bridge not working

Tags: linux, networking, bridge

We want to create bridge (`mybridge`) on our board  over `eth0` and `eth1` interface. The board runs Linux 2.6.34.9.

Following are the commands:

```
brctl addbr mybridge
ifconfig eth1 0.0.0.0
ifconfig eth0 0.0.0.0
brctl addif mybridge eth1
brctl addif mybridge eth0
ifconfig mybridge up
```

PC-----ETH1-----mybridge-------ETH0

When we ping the board from a PC, we are able to receive packet on `eth1` (`eth1` rx counter increasing), but they are not getting transferred to `mybridge`, since the rx counter on `mybridge` is not increasing.
After little search on net we found that 
`mybridge` is up but not going to RUNNING mode. Unless it goes to RUNNING mode, the bridge will not work.

Can anyone please let us why `mybridge` is not entering RUNNING state?

```
/ # ifconfig
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr BC:9A:78:56:34:12  
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

eth1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:E0:0C:BC:E0:00  
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:101 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:3 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:7200 (7.0 KiB)  TX bytes:126 (126.0 B)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

mybridge  Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:E0:0C:BC:E0:00  
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
```

Any sort of input will be of great help.

Comment: How exactly are you "pinging". You don't have an IP address. Your bridge is just a bridge. You don't have an IP interface on it, so nothing is meant to receive packets there. You're just switching/bridging accross eth0 and eth1.

Comment: No IPs anywhere? What are trying to accomplish with that bridge?

Answer (score 2):

You cannot ping the board, because the board does not have an IP address. It is not clear exactly what you are doing here.

Packets are not going through the bridge on the board because there is nothing hanging off eth0 of the board. If you plug a device into eth0 and ping that, you should see the packets go through the bridge.

There may be two reasons why the packet counter of eth0 is not increasing:

1) The bridge operates somewhat like a switch, in that it keeps track of the MAC addresses of the devices behind each port of the bridge. If you run the command `brctl showmacs mybridge`, you can see the MAC addresses of the devices the bridge has seen and which port they are behind.

If you plug a device into eth0 and try and ping it, the pinging host will first broadcast an ARP request to discover the MAC address of the host with the IP address to ping. When that host response to the ARP request, the bridge will see that the host with that MAC address is behind eth0 of the bridge. However, I would expect to see the ARP broadcasts be counted against the interface, so while you'd have a low packet/byte count on eth0, it should be non-zero.

2) There is nothing plugged into eth0, hence it has no carrier. There is no point sending packets on an interface that is unplugged. You can see this with the 'ip link' command (the `ip` command deprecates the `ifconfig` command - you can see the interface counters with `ip -s link`). You will see `NO-CARRIER` against eth0.

Comment: We assigned the IP to bridge but still same result.We carried same test on PC (running ubuntu),by bridging
wireless port and Lan port by using following commands

sudo ifconfig eth0 0.0.0.0
sudo ifconfig wlan0 0.0.0.0
sudo brctl addbr mybridge
sudo brctl addif mybridge eth0
sudo brctl addif mybridge wlan0
sudo ifconfig mybridge 192.168.1.45 netmask 255.255.255.0
sudo ifconfig mybridge up

Here we are able to ping to bridge from another system over wireless. And also mybridge show RUNNING UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST MTU:1500 Metric:1

Comment: we would like add further that

kernel running on PC ---- 3.0.0-24-generic

kernel running on Board ---- 2.6.39.4

Can there be any kernel issue like we need to add any patch to 2.6.39.4

Any sort of input will be of great help, Thanks in advance

Thanks & Regards
Sumit

Comment: You did not say "wireless" in your question. That is very important. Bridging wireless is tricky and often not possible, without some hardware-specific configuration or code. To bridge to wireless, you need to use the 4-address format instead of the regular 3-address format. I have not done wifi bridging for a number of years, so I do not know what the current state is.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue but I solved it by specifying HDADDR parameter in each eth config . so you need to find out the interface mac address by using ifconfig -a command and after that edit each interface config file in /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-ethX and specify the exact mac address for each interface card.
this is also advised by redhat to specify interface HDADDR when you have more that one physical interface card .

"
HWADDR=MAC-address
where MAC-address is the hardware address of the Ethernet device in the form AA:BB:CC:DD:EE:FF. This directive must be used in machines containing more than one NIC to ensure that the interfaces are assigned the correct device names regardless of the configured load order for each NIC's module. This directive should not be used in conjunction with MACADDR.

https://access.redhat.com/site/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Deployment_Guide/s1-networkscripts-interfaces.html
"